# Openfire XEP-0136 - Issues filtering archive with start and end parameters

Tags: xmpp, archive, openfire

I'm using Openfire as my xmpp server and am trying to retrieve archived messages after a particular time using XEP-0136.  I have the monitoring service plugin installed and am able to receive a list of collections but it is not listening to the start and end parameters.

I've searched around and haven't seen others have the same issue...so either they've not tried it (unlikely) or I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my iq:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="get">
   <list xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" start="2014-09-08T17:12:10Z" end="2014-09-08T17:12:56Z">
      <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
         <max>100</max>
      </set>
   </list>
</iq>
```

The only thing that is different between my iq and what is in the XEP-0136 docs (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#example-39) is that I don't specify a with.  I'm trying to get all inbound and outbound messages from the currently logged in user from the start time.

Is there something I'm missing here?  I'd really appreciate your help.

**EDIT**: I have confirmed that adding 'with' does not help.

Comment: Did you ever stumble upon an answer?

Comment: @NoahTernullo no I ended up implementing my own service to do this.

Comment: any chance you could share that service?  I think this is a common problem.

Comment: sorry, I wish I could.  It was not written in a modular way.